# How to toggle class on multiple elements with same class name on click

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I can not get this code to work. 
I am trying to create a function that can listen to click on multiple elements with same class name, and then after click, toggle a specific class name on the next element with a specific class name.
I am trying to use a loop that loops through all the "buttons" (class="click-to-expand") and when you click  a specific button, it should loop through the specific divs and toggle a class name on the next element with (class="expand").

Any help would be very appreciated!

```js
var expandArray = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');

document.querySelectorAll('.click-to-expand').forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.expandArray[0].classList.toggle("hidden");
  })
});
```

```css
.hidden {display: none}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="click-to-expand">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="expand hidden">asd</div>

<br>

<div>
  <div>
    <div class="click-to-expand">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="expand hidden">asd</div>

<br>

<div>
  <div>
    <div class="click-to-expand">+</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="expand hidden">asd</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
var expandArray = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');
var buttonArray = document.querySelectorAll('.click-to-expand');

document.querySelectorAll('.click-to-expand').forEach(function(i) {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const clickedBtnIndex = [...buttonArray].indexOf(e.target);
    expandArray[clickedBtnIndex].classList.toggle("hidden");
  })
});
```

The logic is to find out the index of the button which was clicked and use the same index to find the element in expandArray for which"hidden" should be toggled.

Comment: I did not think about that. Thank you!