# How to toggle between displaying and hiding images created with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I’ve been away awhile, but we always come back, won’t we (even if no one missed us;)?

### What Am I Trying to Achieve

Basically just images, grouped with a primary image.

This primary will always be shown and also serves as the content for link with a OnClick action.

`<a onclick="toggleHidden('ImageGroup1')"><img src="…"></a>`

Clicking the image will then trigger the function *toggleHidden*.
This image will be followed by several images that ideally are hidden by default and can be shown when clicking on the primary image of the group.
Naturally, only the images following the primary image shall toggle between being displayed or hidden.

### What Makes It Harder

I want the title attribute of the image to be dynamic, i.e. has a number that has to be calculated based on the date. I only found this feasible by using JavaScript, meaning I create an image using `const imgName = new Image()` and then add the attributes and classes.
If I put these images into a `<div>` or `<span>` element, give it an id and use `element.getElementById` in my function *toggleHidden*, then the images are still shown. (Btw, I made it work with *ordinary* images, that is images that a created using HTML code like `<img src="">`.)

### In Theory

I tried two functions. First, all images in the same group have the same class (here *ImageGroup1*).

**1st function**:

```js
function showHiddenClassElements(myClassName) {
    var hidimg = document.getElementsByClassName(myClassName);
    if (hidimg.style.display === "none") {
        hidimg.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        hidimg.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I tried several variations, using an inversion like `!== "none"` (and corresponding changes in the code) and different attributes than *initial* or *inline*.

**2nd function**:

```js
function toggleHiddenClass(myClassName) {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName(myClassName);
    element.classList.toggle("hiddenspan");
}
```

…where *hiddenspan* contains only `display: none;` - nothing works.

### My Code

```html
<style>
    .Group2 { }

    .Group3 { }

    .basic {
        width:150px;
        height:225px;
    }

    .hiddenspan {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function myFunction(myDIVid) {
        var x = document.getElementById(myDIVid);
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function showHiddenClassElements(myClassName) {
        var hidimg = document.getElementsByClassName(myClassName);
        if (hidimg.style.display === "none") {
            hidimg.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            hidimg.style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function toggleHiddenClass(myClassName) {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName(myClassName);
        element.classList.toggle("hiddenspan");
    }
</script>

<body>
    <h2>Group 1</h2>

    <a onclick="myFunction('Group1')"><img class="basic" src="01.gif" alt="01" title="01"></a>
    <span id="Group1" class="hiddenspan">
        <img class="basic" src="001.jpeg" alt="001" title="001">
        <img class="basic" src="002.jpeg" alt="002" title="002">
        <img class="basic" src="003.jpeg" alt="003" title="003">
    </span>

    <h2>Group 2</h2>

    <a onclick="showHiddenClassElements('Group2')">
      <img class="basic" src="02.gif" alt="02" title="02">
    </a>

    <script>
        var d1 = new Date(1994,1,31);
        var d2 = new Date();
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
        const img02_001 = new Image();
        img02_001.src = "02/001.jpeg"; 
        img02_001.classList.add("basic"); 
        img02_001.classList.add("Group2");
        img02_001.alt="001";
        img02_001.title="001 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)";
        document.body.appendChild(img02_001);
    </script>

    <script>
        var d1 = new Date(2006,7,23);
        var d2 = new Date();
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
        const img02_002 = new Image();
        img02_002.src = "02/002.jpeg"; 
        img02_002.classList.add("basic"); 
        img02_002.classList.add("Group2");
        img02_002.alt="002";
        img02_002.title="002 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)"; 
        document.body.appendChild(img02_002);
    </script>

    <h2>Group 3</h2>

    <a onclick="showHiddenClassElements('Group3')">
        <img class="basic" src="03.gif" alt="03" title="03">
    </a>

    <script>
        var d1 = new Date(1997,3,31);
        var d2 = new Date();
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
        const img03_001 = new Image();
        img03_001.src = "03/001.jpeg"; 
        img03_001.classList.add("basic"); 
        img03_001.classList.add("Group3");
        img03_001.alt="001";
        img03_001.title="001 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)"; 
        document.body.appendChild(img03_001);
    </script>

    <script>
        var d1 = new Date(2016,10,23);
        var d2 = new Date();
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
        const img03_002 = new Image();
        img03_002.src = "03/002.jpeg"; 
        img03_002.classList.add("basic"); 
        img03_002.classList.add("Group3");
        img03_002.alt="002";
        img03_002.title="002 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)"; 
        document.body.appendChild(img03_002);
    </script>

    <h2>Group 4</h2>

    <a onclick="myFunction('Group4')">
        <img class="basic" src="03.gif" alt="03" title="03">
    </a>

    <span id="Group4" class="hiddenspan">

        <script>
            var d1 = new Date(1997,3,31);
            var d2 = new Date();
            var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
            const img03_001 = new Image();
            img03_001.src = "03/001.jpeg"; 
            img03_001.classList.add("basic"); 
            img03_001.classList.add("Group3");
            img03_001.alt="001";
            img03_001.title="001 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)";
            document.body.appendChild(img03_001);
        </script>

        <script>
            var d1 = new Date(2016,10,23);
            var d2 = new Date();
            var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
            var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
            const img03_002 = new Image();
            img03_002.src = "03/002.jpeg"; 
            img03_002.classList.add("basic"); 
            img03_002.classList.add("Group3");
            img03_002.alt="002";
            img03_002.title="002 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)";
            document.body.appendChild(img03_002);
        </script>
    </span>
</body>
```

Obviously the code has been simplified, especially the HTML part (no `<h1>` header, no HTML declaration), but you should get the idea.

For *Group 1* the code works flawlessly (almost, except for a line break after the primary image, but I could live with that), the same function with images generated with JavaScript (*Group 4*) will display the images, as if the `<span>` element with its `id` and `class` weren’t even there.

The other functions for group 2 and 3 do not work at all, as if `getElementsByClassName` doesn’t work at all. That's what I believe.

***So what do you think?*** Is there a way to toggle the display of these images?

### Edit 1

As Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans suggested, I added an event listener (hopefully the right way):

```html
<script>
    document.getElementById("idGroup3").addEventListener("click", toggleHiddenClass("Group3"));
</script>
```

…and changed the code for Group 3 like this (per suggestion):

```html
<h2>Group 3</h2>

<button id="idGroup3">
    <img class="basic" src="03.gif" alt="03" title="03">
</button>

<script>
    var d1 = new Date(1997,3,31);
    var d2 = new Date();
    var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
    const img03_001 = new Image();
    img03_001.src = "03/001.jpeg"; 
    img03_001.classList.add("basic"); 
    img03_001.classList.add("Group3");
    img03_001.alt="001";
    img03_001.title="001 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)";
    document.body.appendChild(img03_001);
</script>

<script>
    var d1 = new Date(2016,10,23);
    var d2 = new Date();
    var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
    const img03_002 = new Image();
    img03_002.src = "03/002.jpeg"; 
    img03_002.classList.add("basic"); 
    img03_002.classList.add("Group3");
    img03_002.alt="002";
    img03_002.title="002 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)"; 
    document.body.appendChild(img03_002);
</script>
```

Still no effect.

Comment: [Don't use the HTML `onclick` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#registering_event_handlers). Write proper JS that adds normal event listeners based on query selecting (or directly selecting by id or tagname etc) the element(s) you need. Also, don't set `style` values, use `element.classList.add` and `element.classList.remove` to add and remove classes - the only direct manipulation your JS should be doing with `style` is setting/updating CSS variables so that CSS takes care of the rest.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, for answering.

Comment: Unfortunately, your link uses buttons (which I don’t want to use), and my knowledge in JS is very, very rusty. And you meant the style manipulation in the function showHiddenClassElements? I did not create it, I’ not yet that good in JS. :) Let’s try and find some better info on event handling using a link, shall we (I)?

Comment: I didn't, nothing I've said is an answer, it's just a comment. As for `button` or `a`, that's irrelevant, the link explains event handling in "modern" JS (as in, ever since HTML5 replaced HTML4.01, about a decade ago).

Comment: Use a button when it triggers an action on the page. https://www.buttoncheatsheet.com/

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans A reponse is also an answer, as it may lead to a solution :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don’t want to - a button is aesthetically unsatisfying. There must be another way.

Comment: Beside, using a button (as in <button id="idGroup3"><img class="basic" src="03.gif" alt="03" title="03"></button>) has no effect either but looks ugly.

Comment: No HTML element "looks ugly": the look of a `<button>` or `<a>` are, _like all HTML elements_ determined by CSS, so use CSS that makes them look the way you want them to. If the user action does not trigger a navigation action to a different page, or different part of the page, do not use an `<a>` element (because that's the _only_ thing an `<a>` should be used for in HTML5). Use a `<button>` and then style it however you want (including display:inline, removing any border, explicitly setting no background, forcing an underline on hover/focus, and anything else you need)

Comment: As I said, I already did. It still does not work.

Comment: Now tried the following code: document.getElementById(idGroup3").addEventListener("click", function() { var element = document.getElementsByClassName("Group3"); element.classList.toggle("hiddenspan"); } - either it does not recognize the images by the class Group3 or it does not toggle the class hiddenspan for these images.

Comment: I believe the problem lies with the method document.getElementsByClassName - it results in an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) - I probably need to include a loop to get to toggle a class to each of its elements.

Comment: I just tried `function toggleHiddenClass(myClassName) {
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName(myClassName);
    for (subelement of element){
    subelement.classList.toggle("hiddenspan");
}}`, alas to no avail…

Comment: Found this question: [How to toggle class on multiple elements with same class name on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716364/how-to-toggle-class-on-multiple-elements-with-same-class-name-on-click), and I am checking it out, but so far it eludes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution.

The problem was neither button nor the event listener (though it certainly is a more proper solution with both) but the question how to iterate the HTMLCollection returned by *getElementsByClassName*.

Identifying this as the cause of my problem took some testing (thanks to the Google Chrome DevTools). And the first step to the full solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return). The second part came from the German website [mediaevent.de](https://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/add-event-listener-arguments.html), with some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024483/how-to-pass-parameter-to-function-using-in-addeventlistener) for a better understanding of the code.

```
<html>

<head>

<style>
.basic {
width:150px;
height:225px;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hiddenspan {
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
function functionButton(className) {
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className))
    .forEach((element) => element.classList.toggle("hiddenspan"));
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Group 1</h2>

<button class="button" id="buttonGroup1"><img class="basic" src="01.gif" alt="01" title="01"></button>
<img class="basic imgGroup1 hiddenspan" src="01/001.jpeg" alt="01: 001" title="01: 001">
<script>
        var d1 = new Date(1994,1,31);
        var d2 = new Date();
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
        const img01_002 = new Image();
        img01_002.src = "01/002.jpeg"; 
        img01_002.classList.add("basic");
        img01_002.classList.add("imgGroup1");
        img01_002.classList.add("hiddenspan");
        img01_002.alt="01: 002";
        img01_002.title="01: 002 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)";
        document.body.appendChild(img01_002);
    </script>

<script>
const elementButtonGroup1 = document.getElementById("buttonGroup1");
elementButtonGroup1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    functionButton("imgGroup1");
    }, false
    );
</script>

<h2>Group 2</h2>

<button class="button" id="buttonGroup2"><img class="basic" src="02.gif" alt="02" title="02"></button>
<img class="basic imgGroup2 hiddenspan" src="02/002.jpeg" alt="02: 001" title="02: 001">
<script>
        var d1 = new Date(2016,10,23);
        var d2 = new Date();
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        var daydiff = (diff / 31557600000);
        const img02_002 = new Image();
        img02_002.src = "02/002.jpeg"; 
        img02_002.classList.add("basic");
        img02_002.classList.add("imgGroup1");
        img02_002.classList.add("hiddenspan");
        img02_002.alt="02: 002";
        img02_002.title="02: 002 ("+Math.floor(daydiff)+" years old)";
        document.body.appendChild(img02_002);
    </script>

<script>
const elementButtonGroup2 = document.getElementById("buttonGroup2");
elementButtonGroup2.addEventListener("click", function() {
    functionButton("imgGroup2");
    }, false
    );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Working with buttons, you need to add a specific script for each button, then add an event listener to the aforementioned button. And this code can be simplified like this:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("buttonGroup1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    functionButton("imgGroup1");
    }, false
    );
</script>
```

It works on both kinds of images. In this example, the images are hidden by default.

By the way, even if a *button* is the better solution, it does worked with `<a onclick="functionButton('imgGroup1')"><img class="basic" src="01.gif" alt="01" title="01"></a>` instead of `<button class="button" id="buttonGroup1"><img class="basic" src="01.gif" alt="01" title="01"></button>` (and without the script to add an event listener to each button and without the need to style the button).