# If I get Elements by Class Name, how do I access their Class List, so that I can add/remove/toggle Classes

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, getelementsbyclassname

linked to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76791158/how-to-toggle-between-displaying-and-hiding-images-created-with-javascript), I ran into the following problem.

I have several elements (in my case, images) with the same class (say "image1"). Using a button, I want to toggle (add and remove) a class (hiding and showing the pictures).

I use `document.getElementsByClass("image1")` to *get* those *elements* (images). Now I need to toggle the class - unfortunately, I can’t get it to.

My first instinct (coming from *getElementById*) was

```
var elementImg = document.getElementsByClass("image1");
elementImg.classList.toggle("hiddenclass");
```

…where *hiddenclass* contains the single line `display:none;` (and for the fun of it I also tried *const* instead of *var*).

But (to little surprise) it does not work, as getElementsByClass returns not a single element, but a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

And no matter how I search the web, I can not find a solution and a hint that eventually works.

Maybe someone among you already encountered this problem and can provide a solution.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Apparently [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) has the method ***.toggleClass()***, but I have little to no notion of jQuery, and it does not seem to solve the problem to access multiple elements with the same class.

---

Using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return), here's the answer to the above mentioned problem:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("image1"))
    .forEach((element) => element.classList.toggle("hiddenspan"));
```

…and it worked like charm.

Comment: You need to loop over the elements that are returned, since it's returning all the elements with the class.

Comment: Or index it: `elementImg[0].classList.toggle("hiddenclass")` but this will only toggle one of them, not all of them.